# Access VBA to find & move recurring value

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, vba

Good Morning,

I'm fairly new to Access VBA and I've been trying to find a solution to a problem:

I've created a form from which users upload an excel file to a database. File open prompt appears, user selects the file, temp table gets created and data gets pulled to this table. From there a set of macros populate the required fields and push the complete set to a perm table and then temp table gets deleted. Now I would like to take it a step further and try and count how many times a value has been uploaded to the table...

Lets say that the value appears in the table twice already, then if user tries to upload the same value for the third time it will be uploaded to a different table. Bear in mind that the file which users will upload may contain values that will be uploaded for the first, second, third, etc. time.

Do you have any suggestions or solutions to my problem? Is it even possible? If yes then how can I make Access to distinguish which records are being uploaded for the first, second, third, etc. time and follow appropriate paths?

I've been scouting the internet for several days now, but no one seems to have such issue.

Thank you in advance for replies.

Comment: What method are you using to import? If you are using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`, then this might be a far fetched solution. You can after upload, could use a DCount on the Temp table, compare it with the DCount of Perm table then move it accordingly.

Comment: I use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`, however if this is problematic then I'm not opposing to a different solution. Would you be able to provide some code to count & compare values from those 2 tables?

Comment: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` is ***not*** problematic. It is just not cutting the bill for you on this occasion.

Comment: OK, do you have any solutions to the problem? Like I said, I'm new to Access VBA, therefore I'm relying on you expertise. Thanks!

Comment: No joy with this one then... Any thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow. You are essentially trying to prevent inserting duplicate data to a production table and if a duplicate is encountered at the record to a different table?

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to check if record that's about to be added already was added to the database, but not more than twice. If user would like to add it for the third time then that's where all the magic should've happened. 

I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: You might be able to use a multi-field unique index with a version column. The first row would have a version column value of, say, 0 and the second 1 and any subsequent values default to 0. That way the table kicks out third and subsequent duplicate records. You could then take the kicked-out records and add them to another table. Just a thought...

Comment: I am unsure on how to do this. Would you be so kind and share an example on how to do this ? Might be worth checking...

Comment: Overall it's pretty simple. In the table designer, you go to the indexes section and create an index. From there you can add the fields. Be sure to select "Yes" for unique (default is "No"). One of the fields in this index can be the "version" column. Once this is complete, the table will kick out any data inserted that is duplicated. If you want to add data a second or third time, etc. just increment the version column.